# How to simplify WHERE clause with group by conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

**Need SQL help as I am new to writing SQL Queries**

Given below are the sample table structure and the sample `GROUP BY` result

[image]

Assuming that the table can have a very large no of records by having different column values.

The output I am expecting is the sum of each different group as per the user selection.

**e.g:** below is the expected output:

[image]

Here is the **SQL Query** which I am using to fetch the above shown result:

```
SELECT project,
       grant,
       program,
       department,
       SUM(amount) AS Total
FROM   tran_table
WHERE  ( project = 'pj1'
         AND grant = 'gr1'
         AND program = 'pg1'
         AND department = 'dp1' )
        OR ( project = 'pj3'
             AND grant = 'gr2'
             AND program = 'pg1'
             AND department = 'dp2' )
        OR ( project = 'pj6'
             AND grant = 'gr3'
             AND program = 'pg2'
             AND department = 'dp1' )
GROUP  BY project,
          grant,
          program,
          department
```

**Question:**

Is this a correct way to write the **SQL Query** with all different group values in the `WHERE` condition when the expected output could be for 100 different groups?

Comment: You could replace it with `IN` operator., like `project IN ('pj1', 'pj3', 'pj6') AND grant IN(...) ...`

Comment: Can't you put the criteria into a permanent or a temporary table? In that case you just need to `inner join` on all 4 fields.

Comment: No you **can't** @ReinisVerbelis you are not interested in selected `project` *and* selected `grant`s etc. but in selected combinations of `project, grant, program, department`

Comment: Yes @MarmiteBomber You are correct the criteria should be a combination of all.  Selecting an individual will not solve the purpose.

Comment: Hi, @DávidLaczkó Thanks for the suggestion. Would you mind having a sample script showcasing putting criteria into a temp/permanent table?

Comment: As I commented above: the table could have those 4 fields as in the `WHERE` clause, possibly having a Primary key on all to avoid duplicates, or have an `ID` column as well as that is good practice and that could be the Primary key, and the other 4 can have a Unique index to avoid duplicates. If you don't know how to create tables, then you should google it and also look in your DB for similar designs and follow the practice used, or ask another question about DB design.

Comment: Thank you @DávidLaczkó. Got you but unfortunately, I have only access to the table structure where I can only query the result out of it. Though your solution looks promising however due to the DB limitations I need to look for the other solution and that may be providing the group in `Where` condition as suggested in another answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine for a `100` selections, you will fail with more than 1000 selections which  is the `IN` list Oracle restriction.

You may use the following `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE  (project, grant, program, department) in 
(('pj1', 'gr1', 'pg1', 'dp1'),
 ('pj3', 'gr2', 'pg1', 'dp2'),
 ('pj6', 'gr3', 'pg2', 'dp1')
)
```

As this is reporting query leading to *full table scan* on large table you need not care much about bind variables and limiting the *parsing*. You should however care about checking the user input to prevent the *SQL injection*.

Of course the alternative is to use a *temporary* table filled with the input data with an `INNER JOIN` to filter the data.

Comment: As a side note, this looks better than the original query, but I won't put this much data into program code, only if this is the only option, so the table solution would be much better.